# Where condition can be a list in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause

I have this :

```
private List<int> linesId = new List<int>();
_materialRepository.ViewLineMaterialStatus()
                   .Where(i => i.LineId == linesId)
                   .Tolist();
```

Can I assign a list in the `where` clause ?

Comment: What do you actually want here? You're not assigning the results of your query to a new list and you're trying to compare a property (`LineId`) to an empty list (`LinesId`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't *assign* it - but you should be able to query it like this:

```
private List<int> linesId = new List<int>();
_materialRepository.ViewLineMaterialStatus()
                   .Where(i => linesId.Contains(i.LineId))
                   .Tolist();
```

Comment: How can i do it if it's a list of object ?